# VB.NET-LINQ compare two datatables

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have two datatables (treno1 and treno2) containing 10 columns about group railway reservation. I need to know if some values in treno1 are on treno2,and catching other values :
for instance I need to know if A last name in treno1 is in treno2 and get other information (car number,seat,and so on)

I get a json reservation from a web.

```
With treno1
    .Columns.Add("Departure", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Arrival", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("PNR", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Level", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Last Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Car", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("seat", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("first name", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("Train", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
    .Columns.Add("ID res", System.Type.GetType("System.String"))
End With


    For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
    
        For Each msg As JObject In item.Values
            treno1.Rows.Add(msg("departureLocationName"), msg("arrivalLocationName"), msg("pnrCode"), msg("serviceLevel"), msg("lastName"), msg("wagon"), msg("seat"), msg("firstName"), msg("transportMeanName"), msg("Id"))
        Next
    Next`
```

how could be a query ?

```
Dim LastName = From n In treno1.AsEnumerable() From n1 In treno2.AsEnumerable
                      Where n.Field(Of String)("Last Name") = n1.Field(Of String)("Last Name") And n.Field(Of String)("Last Name") IsNot Nothing And n.Field(Of String)("first name") = n1.Field(Of String)("first name")
                      Select n1.Field(Of String)("Last Name") + " " + n1.Field(Of String)("first name") + " , " + n1.Field(Of String)("PNR") + " , " + n1.Field(Of String)("Departure") + " - " + n1.Field(Of String)("Arrival")
```

Comment: The `where` is redundant with the `join` - it already filters `treno1` to just rows with `LastName` in `treno2` What is wrong with your query?

Comment: the reality ? i'm not getting the logic of the query.-to find if mr smith it's on treno1 and in treno2 ,and retrieve additional data of his reservation (car,seat,level) how should be ?

Comment: Your query appears fine without the redundant `Where` clause - `matched` should contain the full records from `treno1` that have a `LastName` matching in `treno2`.

Comment: i solved with the right query ....it was the select made wrong.i changed IT